# There is a 4x4 checkerboard and we have 3 shapes to use to tile. right and isosceles triangle and a parallelogram. How many ways to be tiled?

Tags: problem-solving, tiling

So I know that the right triangle is 2^16 because each box has 2 right triangle. I don't know about the parallelogram and the isosceles triangle. How would I also figure out about the mix of the three.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the isosceles triangle and the parallelogram?  Are we allowed to use the three shapes in combination?  Can we turn the tiles over?

Comment: We are allowed to use the shapes in combination. I think you can turn it over. All he told us was the angles are 45 degrees.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to do this if you don't know the size of the parallelogram.  I think you should ask your teacher for clarification.